# Why ImportError with Python __future__.absolute_import?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand `from __future__ import absolute_import` makes  the order of the search process from " the nearest directory -> origin directory" to "origin directory -> the nearest", but I cannot why following fails:

```
/package_root
  - __init__.py
  - abc.py
```

( on `__init__.py` )

```
# without this, all works well:
from __future__ import absolute_import 

from .abc import something  # => OK
from . import abc           # => ImportError: Cannot import name abc
import abc                  # => ImportError: No module named abc
```

It is not what I expected. Why cannot import by this? If there are no conflicts of names, isn't it OK?

( Of course I'm sure it is not by circular import, because it also occurs when target is an empty file. )

Comment: In the simple example you describe, `from . import abc` works fine for me on both Python 2.7 and 3.5. Is there more to your situation than this description? e.g. how are you using the package?

Comment: @MarkLongair Actually I'm using Google App Engine standard environment Python 2.7. I think there are no special rules on it, but it may be occured by this. The name of the script which occurs error is `__init__.py` and the target's is `owner_identify.py`, so I'm sure there are no conflicts of name. It occurs when service loads an function of `__init__.py`, and `from . import owner_identify` is placed at the head of `__init__.py`, not in function definition code. Can they be keys of this problem?